# Почему у меня root остается null после добавления элемента

Tags: c#, .net, search, binary, дерево

Пишу класс Binary Search Tree, тут есть 2 из многих методов: Add и AddRec, дело в том что у меня не изменяется root (корневой элемент) и видимо вообще ничего не добавляется. Помогите понять ошибку. Когда я вызываю A.root.value, ну, хочу его в консоль вывести, оказывается что value у null быть не может! короче, у меня это нулл.
Что не так?

```
class Node<T>
{
    public T value;
    public int Height;
    public Node<T> Right;
    public Node<T> Left;
    public Node(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        Right = null;
        Left = null;
    }
}
class BinarySearchTree<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public Node<T> root;

    public BinarySearchTree()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public bool Search(T value)
    {
        return SearchRec(value, root);
    }        

    private bool SearchRec(T value, Node<T> root)
    {
        if (root == null)
            return false;
        if (root.value.Equals(value))
            return true;
        else if (root.value.CompareTo(value) > 0)
            return SearchRec(value, root.Left);
        else
            return SearchRec(value, root.Right);
    }

    public Node<T> Add(T value)
    {
        return AddRec(value, root);
    }

    private Node<T> AddRec(T value, Node<T> root)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = new Node<T>(value);
            return root;
        }
        else if (value.CompareTo(root.value) > 0)
            return AddRec(value, root.Right);
        else if (value.CompareTo(root.value) <= 0)
            return AddRec(value, root.Left);

        return root;
    }

    private Node<T> ReplaceWithSmallest(Node<T> rootReplace, Node<T> rootSmallest) // rootReplace - what to replace, rootSmallest - its right child.
    {
        if (rootSmallest.Left != null)
        {
            return ReplaceWithSmallest(rootReplace, rootSmallest.Left);
        }
        else
        {
            rootSmallest.Left = rootReplace.Left;
            rootSmallest.Right = rootReplace.Right;
            rootReplace = rootSmallest;
            rootSmallest = null;
            return rootReplace;
        }
    }

    public Node<T> Remove(Node<T> root, Node<T> ParentElem, T value)
    {
        if (root.value.CompareTo(value) == 0) // the element has been found
        {
            if (root.Left != null && root.Right != null)
                return ReplaceWithSmallest(root, root.Right); // replace current root element with the element that this function is going to find (second parameter)
            else if (root.Left != null && root.Right == null) // if there's 1 child there
            {
                if (ParentElem.Left.Equals(root)) // if our element is its parent's left son
                    ParentElem.Left = root.Left; 
                else
                    ParentElem.Right = root.Left;
            }
            else if (root.Left == null && root.Right != null)
            {
                if (ParentElem.Left.Equals(root))
                    ParentElem.Left = root.Right;
                else
                    ParentElem.Right = root.Right;
            }
            else if (root.Left == null && root.Right == null)
                root = null;
        }
        else if (value.CompareTo(root.value) > 0) // if the value we're looking for is bigger than current element
        {
            return Remove(root.Right, root, value);     // then go to its right child
        }
        else if (value.CompareTo(root.value) < 0)
        {
            return Remove(root.Left, root, value); // otherwise go to its left child
        }
        return root;
    }
}

class IntBinarySearchTree : BinarySearchTree<int>
{

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntBinarySearchTree A = new IntBinarySearchTree();
        A.Add(12);
        Console.WriteLine(A.root.value);
        A.Add(11);
        Console.WriteLine(A.root.value);
        A.Add(45);
        A.Add(13);
        A.Add(55);


        //Console.WriteLine(A.root.value);
        Console.WriteLine(A.root.Left.value);
        Console.WriteLine(A.root.Right.value);



        Console.ReadKey();
        A.Search(50);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменные, которые Вы передаете вторым параметром в `AddRec`, не меняются в вызывающем коде. Сделайте передачу этого параметра по ссылке.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref

```
public Node<T> Add(T value)
{
    return AddRec(value, ref root);
}

private Node<T> AddRec(T value, ref Node<T> root)
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        root = new Node<T>(value);
        return root;
    }
    else if (value.CompareTo(root.value) > 0)
        return AddRec(value, ref root.Right);
    else if (value.CompareTo(root.value) <= 0)
        return AddRec(value, ref root.Left);

    return root;
}
```